# Fatal error: Cannot redeclare date_add() in

Tags: php, syntax-error, fatal-error

Fatal error: Cannot redeclare date_add() in

```
<?
function get_date() {
 return date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
}
function date_add($dd) {
    return date("Y-m-d H:i:s",mktime(date("H"), date("i"), date("s"), date("m"), date("d")+$dd, date("Y")));
}
function date_del($dd) {
    return date("Y-m-d H:i:s",mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), date("d")-$dd, date("Y")));
}
?>
```

it shows me error at this file? can anyone help me?

Comment: This means that this function is already declared, change its name.

Answer (score 4):

The error message is quite descriptive: [you're redeclaring a core function](http://www.php.net/date_add). The funciton exists, so you can't declare it again.

Whenever you encounter an error message like this, check `www.php.net/<your-function-name>`, if you get a doc page about a function with that name, you know to change the function name, or better yet: use the existing function. Built in functions will almost certainly be faster.

Answer (score 0):

There's a built-in function named [date_add](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-add.php), you're not allowed to replace it with your own function.